# Set last row to certain column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an appscript that copies data from source_sheet to target_sheet. The issue is that sometimes there are formulas in the entire Column Z of target_sheet and my appsheet will only paste data on the bottom of the spreadsheet (starting on row 1000). Is there a way to make the spreadsheet to only check for the last row in target_sheet Column I?

```
function copy_rows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("source_sheet");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('target_sheet');
  const targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  let lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow, 4);  
  
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  let targetCounter = 1;
 
  let targetColumnUniqueIdentifier = targetSheet.getRange(1, 9, targetLastRow + 1, 1).getValues();  
  let existingValuesInTargetSheet = targetColumnUniqueIdentifier.flat();
 
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceRange.getValues().length; i++) {
    let rowValues = sourceRange.getValues()[i];
    let id = rowValues[1];  // unique identifier is in 1st array
    
    if (existingValuesInTargetSheet.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + targetCounter, 8, 1, 4).setValues([rowValues]);
      targetCounter++;
      existingValuesInTargetSheet.push(id); 
    } else {
      console.log("Duplicate value found and skipped.");
    }
  }
}
```

[Entire Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/8P5w249w).

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NjVKx0EWaN63MMSidRRYmwe5ygwk1W_yG5zWcUi9hbQ/edit#gid=1797796521).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function that will calculate the height of any column

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()) { rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
function copy_rows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("source_sheet");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('target_sheet');
  const targetLastRow = getColumnHeight(9, targetSheet, ss);//<<--
  let lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 3, lastRow, 4);

  Logger.log(lastRow);
  let targetCounter = 1;

  let targetColumnUniqueIdentifier = targetSheet.getRange(1, 9, targetLastRow + 1, 1).getValues();
  let existingValuesInTargetSheet = targetColumnUniqueIdentifier.flat();

  for (var i = 0; i < sourceRange.getValues().length; i++) {
    let rowValues = sourceRange.getValues()[i];
    let id = rowValues[1];  // unique identifier is in 1st array

    if (existingValuesInTargetSheet.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + targetCounter, 8, 1, 4).setValues([rowValues]);
      targetCounter++;
      existingValuesInTargetSheet.push(id);
    } else {
      console.log("Duplicate value found and skipped.");
    }
  }
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [getNumRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows) which will return an integer of the number of rows in the range selected

```js
var lastrow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("I1:I1000").getNumRows();
```

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(): Retrieves the currently active spreadsheet.

.getRange("I1:I1000"): Gets the range of cells from row I1 to row I1000.

.getNumRows(): Returns the number of rows in the range.

The lastrow variable now is the integer of the number of rows in the range

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).